# Games Development Questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829843/unity3d-create-prefab-from-a-gameobject-in-scene-by-using-prefabutiliy-createpre) is a specific Unity3d question. I reckon it would be more suited to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Should it be migrated? Is there any way to vote close with that?

At the moment, I've just put the suggestion on in the comments.

Comment: Main point is - it is also suitable to Stack Overflow. No need to migrate something that actually fits the site it was asked on.

Comment: While question is fit for Stack Overflow it is left alone and might get better treatment on Game Development site.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, there is overlap between two sites. If a question fits on more than one site, there is no need to migrate.

It was already pointed out by @Oded that this particular question fits on SO as well as Game Development, so no action is needed.

When a question does need to be migrated to a site for which we have no migration path, you can use a custom off-topic close reason.

I usually use that custom close reason to inform the OP that they can flag their question for moderator attention, and ask to have it migrated. If you do this, it's a good idea to warn them that cross-posting is generally frowned upon.
You can also raise that custom flag yourself; I do think you should let the OP know you did that.

All of this assumes, of course, that the question is otherwise a good question that will be received well on the intended target site.

Comment: And sometimes there is 100% overlap. Everything on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) is on topic for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). (But AU was created first.)

Comment: @Laurel True, but Ask Ubuntu is a special case; IIRC it was a deal between Canonical and Stack Exchange.